# How to convert float to without zeros and points

Tags: c, zero

I'm programming in C language and I'm in doubt with the conversion of floating values.

I have this summarized code that works perfectly:

```
float number = get_float("Number: ");
float convert= number * 100; 
printf("Number: %g\n", convert);
```

Using **printf** with **%g** I can see the **number** without the **zeros** and **points**.

Has I how to get the **same result** of **printf** with **%g**, but *concatenating* in the **float** convert variable and get the conversion directly ?

**Output:**

***I have it:***

```
0.70 ----> 70.000000
```

***I need it:***

```
0.70 ----> 70
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you show some examples of input and desired results?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `sprintf()`, which is like `printf()` but puts the result in a string instead of printing it?

Comment: What if you have `69.99999`?

Comment: I'll add the output value example

Comment: I have 69.000000. I need 69

Comment: you mean [roundf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) ?

Comment: You need to look into format specifiers, in your case `%.0f`

Comment: You need to define it precisely. Do you want to round it as per arithmetic rules? Or you want to truncate it? Or something else?

Comment: You wouldn't be doing monetary calculations with `float`, would you?  [**Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: Anyway, this looks like a part of some currency related CS50 exercise. In such a case using `floats` is a bad idea in general. Use integers for dollars and integers for cents.

Comment: Thank You for All Comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a int. int does not have a decimal part.
Try this

`int convert= number * 100;`

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation of print and specifier %f

```
printf("Number: %.0f\n", convert);
// print floating point with no point and 0
// eg : printf("Number: %.0f\n", 70.0000); -> 70
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Casting`** should do the trick. Here is modified version of ur code which works as required:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  // getting float
  float number = get_float("Number: ");

  // casting to int to get rid of fractional part
  int convert = (int)(number * 100);

  // printing to check
  printf("Number: %d\n", convert);
  
  return (0);
}
```